# Split a string in python

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have python string as follows

```
mystring = "copy "d:\Progrm Files" "c:\Progrm Files\once up on a time""
```

how can I split this string to

```
mylist = [copy,d:\Progrm Files,c:\Progrm Files\once up on a time]
```

When I tried to use `mysring.split(" ")` the spaces `Progrm Files` and `once up on a time` are also getting split.

Comment: Youll have to use a regex to split

Comment: Your examples are invalid python; quotes inside quotes, and backslash escapes.

Comment: Now your code is invalid in a shell context; the shell will interpret the spaces in the same manner and not correctly interpret the command.

Comment: Hi  Martijn

iam getting a  'No closing quotation' error .

Comment: Your quoting is still quite seriously mucked up; you need to double check that your `mystring` is properly quoted for both python and the shell. Compare the example given in my answer with your own code.

Answer (score 9):

You want to take a look at the [`shlex` module](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html), the shell lexer. It specializes in splitting command lines such as yours into it's constituents, including handling quoting correctly.

```
>>> import shlex
>>> command = r'copy "d:\Program Files" "c:\Program Files\once up on a time"'
>>> shlex.split(command)
['copy', 'd:\\Program Files', 'c:\\Program Files\\once up on a time']
```

Answer (score 1):

this regex catches what you want:

```
import re

mystring = "copy \"d:\Progrm Files\" \"c:\Progrm Files\once up on a time\""

m = re.search(r'([\w]*) ["]?([[\w]:\\[\w\\ ]+)*["]? ["]?([[\w]:\\[\w\\ ]+)*["]?', mystring)

print m.group(1)
print m.group(2)
print m.group(3)

>>> 
copy
d:\Progrm Files
c:\Progrm Files\once up on a time
```